# Menu CSS Issue not solving

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu, internet-explorer-7

i have tried so much but can not solved the issue in the top menu bar which is having images in side it. its working in all browsers but not in IE7.

[image]

Page : http://goo.gl/YsWeiL

Comment: I see no problem in FireFox on Linux

Comment: i have tagged the IE7, and also now edited Question with IE7. (sorry)

Comment: Please create a short example on [jsBin](http://jsbin.com). You're not trying to create a scam site,do you?

Comment: IE7 support should be ended. If a user is still on 7, your site is one of many they will have problems, which should motivate them to upgrade. Have you tested your site with elinks yet?

Comment: i want to add bounty  but  it says :  
`question eligible for bounty in 2 days`

Answer (score 0):

Set `z-index=99999` of `ul` and check the `position` is `set` in `ul`

like **css**

```
ul{
   position:relative;
   z-index:99999;
}
```

**Also** the `image` you are showing is `outside` the `ul` it should be in the `li` in which **you want to show**